# Change color by result from mYsql QUERY

Tags: php, mysql

I am very much a beginner at this and have a php built web page that displays status of agents. The status can result in "Ready" "Busy" "Off" I would like to change the color of the text and or field dependant upon the status. Below is the line from the php file that is displaying the status. I have a second file that does the MySQL query to get the result:

```
<td align="center" style="font-size:30px;text-shadow:2px 2px #000000; width:50%; height:50px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($agentstate['state']) ?></td>
```

Comment: Have you not attempted anything? Or should i say what have you attempted?

Comment: use if...else and store color code in a variable

Comment: Sorry like I said I am new to this I have tried the following:         <td align="left" style="font-size:30px;color:#FFFFFF;text-shadow:2px 2px #000000; width:50%; height:60px;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($agentstate['agent'])  if($agentstate['state']==Ready){
     echo "<td color='green'>Data</td>"
    }
    else{
       echo "<td color="white">Data</td>";
    }  ?></td>

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a helper function like this:

```
function getAgentState($state) {
    $color = '#';
    switch ($state) {
        case 'Ready': $color .= '008000'; break; // Green
        case 'Busy': $color .= 'FF5500'; break; // Orange
        case 'Off': $color .= 'FF0000'; break; // Red
        default: $color = .= '000000'; break; // Black - no state match
    }
    echo '<span style="color: '. $color .'">'. $state .'</span>';
}
```

then use it like this:

```
<td align="center" style="font-size:30px;text-shadow:2px 2px #000000; width:50%; height:50px;">
    <?php getAgentState($agentstate['state']) ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Latheesan that was so easy with your explanation!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution is to build an array where the keys are your various agent states.

```
<?php
$states=array(
    'Ready'=>'#ff0000',
    'Busy'=>'#00ff00',
    'Off'=>'#0000ff'
    );
$color=in_array($agentstate['state'],$states)?$state[$agentstate['state']]:'#f0f0f0';

echo '<td align="center" style="color:'.$color.';">'.htmlspecialchars($agentstate['state']).'</td>';
?>
```

If the key exists in the `$states` array it will use the corresponding value, otherwise use a default value.